# excel vba highlighting entire row

Tags: vba, excel

my code is

```
          If (Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row3 + 87 + 1, 14) > 1) Then
             For i = 1 To 16
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row3 + 87 + 1, i).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row3 + 87 + 1, i).Font.Color = vbRed
            Next i
          End If
```

The above code isnt coloring cells as in the above condition; I need to compare it with **100%**.

Comment: You mean you want to change 100 to 100%? Just type it like that (100%), else as (1)

Comment: i have a percent field in dataset so i am comparing it as % but when i add % character after 100 the % sign disappears

Comment: apologies, you're right adding in % won't work dumb idea. there's no percentage type variable in vba, so I think you'll have to change the 100 to a 1, or else multiply the .cells value by 100 to make them equivalent.

Comment: i changed it to 1 but still the cell is not getting highlighted

Comment: well it looks good to me. put a break point on the if line, roll the mouse over sheets and see what the value is at that point.

Comment: Try debugging, apply a breakpoint. Then when the execution comes to the area, you press F8 to step one line at a time, see what is being returned and what you are comparing against. See if the If ever tests true. If not you have found your problem. If it does go in, but does not set the color, check where it is getting changed again.

Comment: it is pointing to the row which is to be highlighted but it is not coloring it

Comment: maybe very dumb idea but can you check if you have any conditional formatting on those cells remaining from past? If you have conditional formatting it will not change the color :)

Comment: The cell has a format of percentages

Comment: cell number formatting is different than what I was trying to mention. After selecting your target row if you go to `Home` in your ribbon you will see a button called `Conditional Formatting` then if you click `Manage Rules` you will be able to see existing rules, if you have of course.

Comment: You should use the debug tools (breaks and inspections) to see the values of `Row3` and the cells content.